# Have add after/before function to jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Is there a way in which i can have , add_before and add_after to a [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)

for example:

```
.bind("add_after.jstree", function (node,data){
      #perform some function 
})
```

Comment: You have to mention the plugin link as well

Comment: I'm using these

 "plugins" : ["types","dnd","ui","crrm","sort","themes","contextmenu","html_data","checkbox" ],

Comment: `$(function () {
 $("#demo2").bind("before.jstree", function (e, data) {}); });`.You can use before function like this.

Comment: I believe there is no `add_after` or `add_before` options in jstree as far the documentation of jstree is concerned

Answer (score 1):

From the [**`documentation`**](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core):

> jsTree uses events to notify of any changes happening in the tree. All
>   events fire on the tree container in the jstree namespace and are
>   named after the function that triggered them.

and

> There is also one special event - before.jstree. This events enables
>   you to prevent an operation from executing.

So you should be able to listen to events before and after a new node gets inserted like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#treeId").bind("before.jstree", function (e, data) {
        if(data.func === "create_node") {
            // This block will execute before inserting a new node
        }
    });

    $("#treeId").bind("create_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            // This block will execute after inserting a new node
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats for the input, but im not restricting the insert, as far as i can understand.

I'm looking into create a node after/before the selected node.

Is there a way to define a "create_node" position ?

Comment: **N.B.** for a complete list of jsTree events, use [this](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event) link. For example, there is also a `ready.jstree` event, which fires after loading.